# regex match extension but exclude a specific file

Tags: javascript, regex

I am in `webpack.config` where I need to include extension to match specific file type, but I need to exclude a specific file. I googled it but didn't find a perfect solution.

What I have : `/\.(?:css|less)$/` -> matches all files that have `.less OR .css` but here I want to add "not only -> *test.something_strict.less*" `/\.(?:css|less|!test.less)$/` where *test.something_strict* is a file name with extension `.less` and only exclude **test.something_strict**

but this didn't work, this matches `.less or .css` and pass through the test.

Comment: I don't fully understand your specifications. But based on your info [is this okay?](https://regex101.com/r/ZLzsbl/1/)

Comment: @Rahul, you get me right.

Comment: Too late to post answer though. ☺☻

Comment: @Rahul, you can post it, as an alternative.

Comment: Well it will be subset of present solution. Not encouraged to do so.

Comment: @anubhava: That's acceptable. `test.less` is not.

Comment: @AshishMishra: Your new specification is totally different from previous one.

Comment: @Rahul, i am Sorry for Edit, but some specific use case i just realize :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`|!test.less` doesn't really negate matching `test.less`. It will literally match `!` before `test.less`.

You can use this regex:

```
/^(?!test\.[^.]+\.less$).+\.(?:css|less)$/m
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6IT1US/2)

`(?!test\.less$)` is a negative lookahead that will assert failure if filename is `test.<anything>.less`.

Comment: i tried, its working -> is there any possibility to change "test.less" to "test.dark.less"  ?  where test.dark is a file name with ".less" extension.

Comment: sure, let me try very quick :)

Comment: Hi, your answer is working fine, can i replace `[^.]+` to strict word like `dark` or `light` ?

Comment: Hi, i tried that but the problem is that also except "light" if i write "dark" ? :(

Comment: You can use `/^(?!test\.(?:light|dark)\.less$).+\.(?:css|less)$/m` to negate both words

Comment: Works like a charm.. Thanks :)